# how to append new data to a existing Data table?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, append

I have data in my datatable which i am getting like this. Now i want to append my table on scrolling. It's like infinite scrolling. I want to add more data in the bottom of my datatable. Is there a way to add new data in to the existing datatable in my scenario? i am trying this way but its not working.

**HTML**

```html
    <table id="mytable" class="display dt-head-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>CreatedOn</th>
                <th>UpdatedOn</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="Userlist">            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Jquery Code**

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            UserRecords()
        });
        function UserRecords() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Manage/ShowAllResult",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(result);                                     
                    $("#mytable").dataTable({
                        data: result,
                        "sDom": "Rlfrtip", //making Columns Resizeable and Reorderable
                        fixedHeader: true,
                        deferRender: true,
                        paging: false,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'firstName' },
                            { 'data': 'lastName' },
                            { 'data': 'userName' },
                            { 'data': 'email' },
                            { 'data': 'phone' },
                            { 'data': 'createdOn', },
                            { 'data': 'updatedOn' },
                            ]
                   });  
}
});
```

**Next 30 Jquery**

```
function appenddata() {
            var table = $("#mytable").DataTable();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Manage/ShowAllResult?count=" + table.rows().count(),
                success: function (appendresult) {
                    debugger;
                    var counter = appendresult.length;
                    console.log(appendresult);
                    finaldata = appendresult;
                    jQuery.each(finaldata, function (i, val) {
                        debugger;
                        table.row.add([
                            val.firstName,                            
                            val.lastName,
                            val.userName,
                            val.email,
                            val.phone,
                            val.createdOn,
                            val.updatedOn,                                                       
                        ]).draw();

                    });

                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: You can take a look at the [scroller](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scroller) option. Depending on the specific behavior you want to see, this may (or may not) meet your needs.

Comment: Also, just as an observation: I am wondering why you have the DataTables initialization code inside a jQuery ajax function. When using DataTables, it's typically [the other way round](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax).

Comment: @andrewjames yes i know about that the problem is how to insert new data in this kind of code.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you mean _create some brand new data and then add that to the table_, then where is this data coming from? How would you handle this situation with standard pagination (i.e. not scrolling)? Perhaps you could [edit] the question to help clarify?

Comment: @andrewjames i am getting 30 records from database on every scroll down request but the problem is i am showing only first 30 i want to append next 30 at the bottom of my existing 30 records in data table. how can i achieve this with this kind of code.

Comment: _"i am getting 30 records from database on every scroll down request"_ How are you doing that? Can you [edit] the question to clarify? What you are describing sounds more like [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), where the server controls sending the next set of records to DataTables.

Comment: @andrewjames ok i updated the code so this is how i am getting next 30 from database now tell me the next code how can i append these 30 to the that table.

Comment: To add new rows of data to the DataTable, you can use the [`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) function. As you can see from the example, it takes a JSON structure - in your case, that would be an array of objects: `[ {...}, {...},...]` representing your next 30 records. Hope that helps!

Comment: @andrewjames yes this is the code i want can you please tell me how can i proper write this code in my case. please write the code for me.

Comment: I can't write the code, because I don't know what your data looks like (and really you should at least try to make an attempt for yourself). But it would be something like this: `table.rows().add(appendresult).draw();`. Like I say, this depends on your data (and the structure of `appendresult`). So I have no idea if this will work or not.

Comment: @andrewjames actully i was trying whole day i fail that is why i post this question here and table.rows().add(appendresult).draw(); is not working also  all data are string and comming in jason format just created and updated is data is date.

Comment: OK - Here is what I recommend: You need to [edit] your question and provide all this information in the question. Also, you need to provide (a) the actual code you are using, showing how you are trying to use `rows.add()`; (b) the related error messages you are receiving in the browser console, formatted as text, not screenshots (instead of only saying "it is not working"); (c) a sample of the data, you are receiving, as text, not screenshots (instead of only saying "it is in JSON format"). The help we can provide is only as good as the information you give us. Right now, we cannot help you.

Comment: The very best way you can help us is to provide a [mre] - ideally, using something like a fully-working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).